# Redirect listening port to Pyro nameserver

Tags: ssh, python, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to set up a [Pyro4](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) nameserver on a remote machine to be accessed locally. The way I'm tackling this problem is by using ssh port forwarding. If I try to set up a Pyro4 nameserver on the same port on which the remote is listening, I get a `socket` error telling me `socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`. I thought that I might be able to redirect connections on remote to the nameserver port.

To give you an idea what I'm trying, see the following commands. First, I set up port forwarding from local to remote.

```
dean@local$> ssh -l dean -L 2223:localhost:2224 remote
```

Remote is listening on port `2224`. On remote I have a Pyro4 nameserver running on port `2225`. Then, if I try to set up local port forwarding on remote, as follows

```
dean@remote$> ssh -N -l dean -L 2224:localhost:2225 remote &
```

I get the following error:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 2224
Could not request local forwarding.
```

I've read a little about using sockets to redirect traffic, but that seems like a much more involved solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without problems on my system. Something is blocking the port on your system.  Here's what I did:

My systems:
A = windows 7, hostname 'neptune'
B = OSX El Capitan, hostname 'phobos'
Both using latest Pyro (but that shouldn't really matter)

On A:  (I'm using git bash shell on Windows here but that shouldn't matter)
- make ssh tunnel to phobos, tunneling the phobos:2224 socket
- in that remote shell, start a name server bound on phobos:2224
Like so:

```
$ ssh -l irmen -L 2223:phobos:2224 phobos
Last login: Tue Feb 21 22:09:15 2017
phobos:~ irmen$ cd Projects/Pyro4/src
phobos:src irmen$ python3 -m Pyro4.naming -n phobos -p 2224
Broadcast server running on 0.0.0.0:9091
NS running on phobos:2224 (192.168.178.20)
Warning: HMAC key not set. Anyone can connect to this server!
URI = PYRO:Pyro.NameServer@phobos:2224
```

You can start the name server on the remote host directly as well after you opened the ssh port tunnel, but I'm doing it here from my windows machine remotely.

Anyway, after that, things work as expected from A:

```
$ hostname
Neptune
$ python -m Pyro4.nsc -n localhost -p 2223 list
--------START LIST
Pyro.NameServer --> PYRO:Pyro.NameServer@phobos:2224
    metadata: ['class:Pyro4.naming.NameServer']
--------END LIST
```

As you can see that is the name server contents of the NS running on Phobos via the ssh tunnel.

Comment: I was able to get this working with my machine. However, when I try to access an object that is registered on remote's Nameserver, I get a `CommunicationError: cannot connect: [Errno 111] Connection refused` error.

Comment: To clarify, on local, I am trying to connect to object `BasicServer` using the following uri: `uri = PYRONAME:BasicServer@localhost:2223`

Comment: Well, you have to make sure that a) the object registers itself with the correct URI that makes sense to clients that look it up;  and b) it will probably have to have its own port tunneled through ssh as well. Because it's a distinct server process it cannot share the tunneled port you're already using to connect to the name server

Comment: Once I forwarded the object port from local to remote everything worked. Thanks for you help

Comment: Glad to hear it, it was a first for me as well to try to get Pyro running through a ssh tunnel :)